# how to parsing variable from controller to javascript and redirect page with a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a form with javascript validation. if the validation is complete i will redirect to another page with javascript. but I need **invoice variable** from a controller that I need to send to the page I point to later.

my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url  : baseURL +"checkout/endVerify_order",
    type : "GET",
    data : {starssecure: csrf, gex: g, almt: addr, prov: na_prop, city: na_cit, w: wei, exp: ex, resex: exresul, pay: mePay, bnk: bnkifyes, grt: gTotat},
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(".bg-form-che").removeClass("hidden");
    },
    success: function (sndOrder){
        $(".bg-form-che").addClass("hidden");
        if(sndOrder == "Lnswg&g2390"){
            $(".bnk_in").html("Choose Bank!");
            $(".alam_in").html("");
            $(".ex_in").html("");
            $(".prop_in").html("");
            $(".city_in").html("");
            $(".resex_in").html("");
            $(".pay_in").html("");
            $(".pushp").html("Lengkapi Form diatas!");
            $(".citKey").removeClass("border-error");
            $("#addrKey").removeClass("border-error");
            $("#propKey").removeClass("border-error");
            $(".tb_result").removeClass("border-error");
        }else if(sndOrder == "validate_complete"){
            $("#inv").val(sndOrder.datap);
            window.location.href = baseURL + 'finishorder';
        }
    }
    });
```

and my controller :

```
function endVerify_order(){
echo "validate_complete";
$invoice = "AB18253";
$datap = $invoice;
echo json_encode($datap);
}
```

and my view for finishorder :

```
div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="shf" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class=" text-center">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok bort"></i><br>
                <h4>Your Order is Successfully</h4>
                <b>No. Invoice #<span id="inv"></span></b>
                <p class="text-justify">Thankyou for Order.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Controller, jsonize the values as following,

```
function endVerify_order(){
$data['status'] =  "validate_complete";
$data['invoice'] = "AB18253";
$data['datap'] = $invoice;
echo json_encode($data);exit;
}
```

Now you can directly check if(sndOrder.invoice == "Lnswg&g2390"){ }

```
    window.location.href = baseURL + 'finishorder/'+sndOrder.invoice;
```

You can access in controller function,

```
function finishorder($invoiceid)
{ 
    //$invoiceid which is sent from javascript
}
```

Comment: the result is : S5ihs7Hdf52lpP{json: "ST142U432180917"}
json : "ST142U432180917". not redirect page

Comment: the result json in controller is correct, but for parsing it to javascript it read undefined

Comment: hi i updated the json_encode as $data from $datap. Now it will work